# `trim` not working in PHP

Tags: php, string

I have a form which when submitted, an array will be passes. The elements inside that array will be separated using rxml. This is how I tried:

```
$options = $this->request->data('options');

$count = count ($options);
$rxml = "<rslist>";
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
     $trimmedOption = trim($options[$i], "    ");
$rxml = $rxml.'<rs option="'.$trimmedOption.'" />';
}
$rxml = $rxml . "</rslist>";
```

When an element is converted in to a string, first it gets trimmed, because there is some white space in right side of the string. Like this `opton-1`.
In order to remove that space, I used that trim option. But, this is not working.
I tried:

```
str_replace(' ', '', $options[$i]);
rtrim($options[$i]);
```

too. But, nothing worked. That string got saved with that extra space only. So, what should I do? What should I change?

Comment: Have you tried using trim without a second parameter?

Comment: you are currently trimming *four* spaces. so when PHP encounters only *one* space, it doesn't trim it.

Comment: @YuryFedorov: Yes, but no reaction.

Comment: are you sure, that you have whitespaces at the end? Maybe it's a tab?

Comment: @mirko911 `trim` also trims that

Comment: Can you post the value of $options here?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure. This is the string stored in the DB: `one    `

Comment: Then its the code that saves it in the database which creates this issue

Comment: @ManhNguyen:  Wait a sec, I'll show you the array.

Comment: @ManhNguyen This is my array: `Array [ "Kings    ", "Queens    ", "Jacks    " ]`

Comment: @FranzGleichmann: So what can do?

Comment: I would fix the code that saves the data onto the database

Comment: @duddosai http://phpio.net/s/147q
Hmmm....

Comment: @ManhNguyen: Do you mean my code works fine, coz I don't find any change in it?

Comment: @ManhNguyen: `King   �Queen   �Jack   �{"fieldid":"32","message":"Saved successfully!"}` This is what I got when I tried printing mine.

Comment: @ManhNguyen: I tried working out what you gave.`one    <rslist><rs option="one    " />two    <rslist><rs option="one    " /><rs option="two    " />three    <rslist><rs option="one    " /><rs option="two    " /><rs option="three    " />{"fieldid":"35","message":"Saved successfully!"}` Got this.

Comment: @RiggsFolly: The prob is with this only dude. Not with the procedure.

Comment: Ah I see I am guessing you have not set your database tables to be UTF-8 so when you store a character in the extended utf-8 char set, it gets saved as an unprintable character and when you print an unprintable character you always get this �

Comment: @RiggsFolly: The DB is rightly set. The problem is with the code only. I've shown the response in the above comment. Check that out. And is there any relation with DB, for me getting this kinda response?

Comment: Then the page has not been set to utf-8 or the connection has not been set to utf-8 or something in the data supply chain

Comment: @RiggsFolly: But, I don't get that � everytime.